# is Ruby really not scalable? or just Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby on Rails scalability/performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503684/ruby-on-rails-scalability-performance)

I'm aware from the twitter shortages that Ruby on Rails can sometimes prove difficult when scalability becomes an issue. I'm wondering though.. Ruby on it's own.. does it lack scalability?

Comment: If this question was only asking about Rails, it'd be an exact duplicate, but it also asks about Plain Old Ruby Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Ruby on Rails scalability/performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503684/ruby-on-rails-scalability-performance), read Keith's answer. This is very opinionated, but Twitter seems to be an example of how to design a system that doesn't scale. I don't think their issues are predominantly in their choice of language.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is a general-purpose language.

There is nothing more or less scalable about Ruby than C#, Java, Python, "general purpose language X" or even Haskell (although some argue that code which is *forced* to be side-effect free is more scalable; this doesn't preclude writing code with only localized effects in Ruby, e.g). [Note that I have excluded languages explicitly designed to be massively-distributed scalable such as Erlang or those that use MPI for the sake of keeping the argument simple].

Remember that Ruby on Rails is just *one framework* for *one environment* that follows *one approach*.